# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(3i)^k}{k!}}$ converges .

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

by the ratio test:$$\bigg |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\bigg |=\frac{\frac{(3i)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{(3i)^k}{k!}}=\frac{3i\cdot k!}{(k+1)!}=\frac{3i\cdot k!}{k!\cdot (k+1)}=\frac{3i}{k+1}\overset{k\to \infty} \longrightarrow 0$$ Is that ok?

Comment: You forgot to take the modulus of the $i$ term (assuming it refers to the imaginary unit or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be cautious as I am uncertain if $i$ is positive. You might want to keep the absolute value sign.

$$\frac{3|i|}{k+1} \to 0$$

Comment: Ok, thanks. Otherwise it's fine?

Comment: yup, it seems fine.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.